# Run Scales XML's pullXml in weblogic server

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

I used pullXml due to the file size is quite large, > 100M, I wrote a sample program as follows:

```
object TestXml {
    val mc = new java.math.MathContext(1024)
    val zero = BigDecimal(0, mc)

    def calculate(infile: String, encoding: String): BigDecimal = {
        val inStream = new FileInputStream(infile)
        val pull = pullXml(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(inStream, encoding)))
        val ns = Namespace("urn:abcaus.onair.sintecmedia.com")
        val qnames = List(ns("ePGResp"), "EPGResponse"l, "Event"l)
        def eventStream = iterate(qnames, pull).toStream 
        var count = zero
        eventStream foreach { event => count += eventId(event) }
        inStream.close
        count
    }

    def eventId(event: XmlPath): Long =
        text(event.\*("EventID")).toLong

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = args.toList match {
        case infile :: encoding :: Nil => println(calculate(infile, encoding))
        case _ => println("usage scala -cp classpath au.net.abc.epg.TestLoadXml infile encoding")
    }
}
```

I run the program on a command line as follows:

```
    $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp JarContainsSampleProgram.jar:scala-library-2.10.2.jar:scala-reflect-2.10.2.jar:scalalogging-slf4j_2.10-1.0.1.jar:scalaz-core_2.10-7.0.0.jar:scalaz-effect_2.10-7.0.0.jar:scalaz-iterv_2.10-7.0.0.jar:scales-xml_2.10-0.6.0-M1.jar:slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar TestLoadXml /home/wonga4d/EPG/Huge.xml utf-16
```

It runs successfully returning a value, say, 879452677392.

However, when I deploy it as a oracle service bus Java callout (which is ok because Scala is JVM lang) to be used by an OSB proxy, still use the same input file and encoding, I got the following error

```
Callout to java method "public static scala.math.BigDecimal au.net.abc.epg.TestLoadXml.calculate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)" resulted in exception: Got an event (Text()) that should not be in the prolog java.lang.RuntimeException: Got an event (Text()) that should not be in the prolog
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:142)
at scales.utils.package$.error(package.scala:19)
at scales.xml.parser.pull.PullUtils$$anonfun$getMisc$1.apply(PullIterator.scala:144)
at scales.xml.parser.pull.PullUtils$$anonfun$getMisc$1.apply(PullIterator.scala:141)
at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
at scales.xml.parser.pull.PullUtils$.getMisc(PullIterator.scala:141)
at scales.xml.parser.pull.XmlPull$class.start(PullIterator.scala:89)
at scales.xml.parser.pull.XmlPulls$$anon$1.start(XmlPull.scala:134)
at scales.xml.parser.pull.XmlPulls$$anon$1.<init>(XmlPull.scala:156)
at scales.xml.parser.pull.XmlPulls$class.pullXml(XmlPull.scala:134)
at scales.xml.package$.pullXml(package.scala:7)
at TestXml$.calculate(TestLoadXml.scala:23)
at TestXml.calculate(TestLoadXml.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at stages.transform.runtime.JavaCalloutRuntimeStep$1.run(JavaCalloutRuntimeStep.java:173)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:61)
at stages.transform.runtime.JavaCalloutRuntimeStep.processMessage(JavaCalloutRuntimeStep.java:195)
at com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.debug.DebuggerRuntimeStep.processMessage(DebuggerRuntimeStep.java:74)
at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:346)
at com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.PipelineStage.processMessage(PipelineStage.java:84)
```

It fails at pullXml.  But it always succeeds when running on a commandline which I showed before.  If I don't use pullXml but loadXml, it will always succeed even when running in a weblogic server.  But loadXml will get a problem if loading a huge xml file.  Both pullXml &  loadXml methods are located in the same jar, scales-xml_2.10-0.6.0-M1.jar.

Just wonder if anyone ever used scales xml in weblogic server.  Sounds like I got to give up using scales xml if weblogic server is the execution environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that your code runs outside of weblogic shows its a javax.xml implementation issue.  Its possible that this only needs you to supply an alternate implementation (e.g. aalto-xml) with a "child first" or app first classloader setting.

If you could let me know (answering here is cool) if that sorts things out that would be great, I'll add it to the docs.

Outside of this issue I hope Scales is working out for you :)

Cheers,
Chris